# Are there multiple solutions to $P \ \cap J \ \cap \ C$ in this question?

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics

> A professor in a discrete mathematics class passes out a form asking students to tick all the mathematics and computer science courses they have recently taken. The finding is that out a total of $50$ students in the class
>
> - $30$ took precalculus
> - $18$ took calculus
> - $26$ took java
> - $9$ took both precalculus and calculus
> - $16$ took both precalculus and Java
> - $8$ took both calculus and Java
> - $47$ took at least one of the three courses
>
> **Question:** How many students took all three courses?

If we let $P = \text{Precalculus}$, $J = \text{Java}$, $C = \text{Calculus}$ and draw out a Venn Diagram, we can see $P \ \cap J \ \cap \ C = 0$. But just by testing some other numbers another possible solution is $P \ \cap J \ \cap \ C = 6$. Both Venn Diagrams work and are valid.

Do multiple solutions exists to this question, or is one of $0$ or $6$ correct? If multiple solutions do exist why is that so?

Comment: See [Inclusion–exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) : $|P \cup J \cup C| = |P| + |J|+ |C| - |P \cap J| - |P \cap C| - |C \cap J| + |P \cap J \cap C|$ and solve for $|P \cap J \cap C|$.

Comment: Can you show the calculations for the Venn diagram you have made? The answer looks like being $6$ to me, and I made a Venn diagram myself.

Answer (score 1):

You must have drawn the Venn diagram incorrectly. Here is the correct one:

[image: Venn diagram]

To obtain it I used the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), which in this case says that

$$|P\cup J\cup C|=|P|+|J|+|C|-|P\cap J|-|P\cap C|-|J\cap C|+|P\cap J\cap C|\;.$$

Since $|P\cup J\cup C|=50-3=47$, we know every term of this except $|P\cap J\cap C|$; solving for it, we find that $|P\cap J\cap C|=6$, and the rest of the Venn diagram can then be filled in by working out from the centre. That is, we first calculate the $10,2$ and $3$, and once we have those, we calculate the $11,8$ and $7$.